# matlibplot not showing up ssh into rasp pi

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh

I'm trying to generate a plot using python while ssh into a rasp pi. I tried a few different things but I can't get the plot to show up or I am getting Traceback errors.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print ('start')
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,9,16])
plt.show()
print ('finished')
```

> start
>
> finished

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print ('start')
plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,9,16])
plt.show()
print ('finished')
```

> start
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "run_ssa_test1.py", line 20, in 
>       plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,9,16])
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3306, in plot
>       ax = gca()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 950, in gca
>       return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 586, in gcf
>       return figure()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
>       **kwargs)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 81, in new_figure_manager
>       return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 89, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
>       window = Tk.Tk()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1854, in **init**
>       self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
>   _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Answer (score 1):

To *show* an image, matplotlib, or any other tool, needs a display to show it on.  SSH logins by default only give console access.

The two most obvious options that I see are:

1. generate images on the raspberry pi, write them to file, and retrieve them to your local machine to display.

```
   host$ ssh rpi_hostname
   rpi$ python make_images.py
   # where `make_images.py` contains something like
```

```py
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,9,16])
   plt.savefig("myfig.png", bbox_inches='tight', ...)
```

```
   rpi$ logout
   host$ scp rpi_hostname:myfig.png .
   host$ display myfig.png
```

This example uses `display`, a tool from imagemagick. but obviously change display to `eog`, `gthumb`, or whatever you have installed.

---

2. login to the raspberry pi with X-forwarding on:

```
host$ ssh -X hostname
```

Now images generated on the rpi can be rendered on a display that is shown on your host machine, i.e. `pyplot.show()` will work.

Option (2) can be rather slow, and it also depends on having more libraries for the backends installed on the rpi.

---

A third option would be to avoid plot generation on the rpi altogether, instead retrieving the data to your host pc and plotting there.